# Divisibility by $33^{33}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $P_n=(19+92)(19^2+92^2)\cdots(19^n+92^n)$ for each positive integer $n$. Determine , with proof the least positive integer $n$, if it exists , for which $P_n$ is divisible by $33^{33}$.

I have made no progress concrete enough to show .

Comment: As a hint, $33=3\times 11$.  Therefore you can solve the problem for $3$ and $11$ separately.

Comment: Well, you might start by splitting the question into two parts.  What power of $3$ is $P_n$ divisible by?  What power of $11$?

Comment: I did write $33=(11.3)^{33}$ . So , for $P_n$ to be divisible by $33^{33}$ , we need to have $P_n$ divisible by $3^{33}$ and $11^{33}$ . I can't go any further . What to do next ?

Comment: Start with $3$.  Analyze each term in the product for divisibly by powers of $3$. Then do the same for $11$.

Comment: @Italian where did you get this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Modulo $3$, we have
$$19^k+92^k\equiv 1^k+(-1)^k\pmod 3 $$
and this is $0$ iff $k$ is odd. So for each odd $k$, the factor $19^k+92^k$ adds (at least) one factor $3$; and for even $k$, it doesn't. 
This alone gives us 
$3^m\mid P_{2m-1}$, or equivalently
$$3^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor}\mid P_n. $$
There *may* be higher powers of $3$ added by such a factor. Indeed, 
$$19^k+92^k\equiv 1+2^k\equiv 0\pmod 9\iff k\equiv 3\pmod 6.$$
This improves our estimate to 
$$3^{\lfloor\frac{n+1}2\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{n+3}6\rfloor}\mid P_n. $$
Hence for $3^{33}$, $n=49$ would be *sufficient*, but this is still not optimal (though we may suspect that we should rather do more work for the second part - divisibility by $11^{33}$).

So let's look at $11$:
We have $19\equiv -3\pmod{11}$ and $92\equiv 4\equiv (-3)\cdot 6\pmod{11}$, hence
$$19^k+92^k\equiv(-2)^k(1+6^k)\equiv 0\pmod{11} \iff k\equiv 5\pmod {10}.$$
This gives us
$$ 11^{\lfloor\frac{n+5}{10}\rfloor}\mid P_n.$$
Incidentally, we verify that $11^2\|19^5+92^5$ so that 
$$ 11^{2\lfloor\frac{n+5}{10}\rfloor}\mid P_n.$$
From this, we find that $n=165$ will certainly be *sufficient*.

For the exact result (which is readily found numerically: $n=155$), you will need to investigate the factors modulo $1331$ (and even $14641$), I am afraid.

Comment: FYI $19^{55} + 92^{55} \equiv 0 \pmod{1331}$. Given that the answer was numerically found to be 155, we can guess that the solution is a multiple of 5 between $ \frac{165}{4} , \frac{165}{3}$.

Answer (score 1):

$19\equiv 1 (mod 3)$
$92\equiv -1(mod 3)$

Checking $P_1$

$19+92\equiv 1-1 (mod 3)$

Hence $P_1$ is a multiple of $3^1$,

Similarly you can find values of $n$ for which $3^k|19^n+92^n$

Then add all $k$ until sum of $k=33$

Can you repeat a similar argument for $11$

Comment: @h-squaredwell $19^2+92^2$ is not divisible by 3

Comment: Knowing that $3$ divides $P_n$ for all $n$ doesn't help much.  It is certainly not true that $3$ divides each of the factors $19^k+92^k$.  More to the point, $3$ really isn't the problem here.

Comment: I actually meant that the whole expression is divisible by $3^1$, It was mentioned as a hint for the OP to figure out $3^33$ on their own

Comment: I have still editted my answer, to avoid any confusions

Comment: Best do the argument for $11$ first.   By the time you've done $33$ terms divisible by $11$ you will have done *many* more than $33$ terms divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The divisibility by $3$ of many factors of $P_n$ does not present any difficulties. So let's look only at the factors divisible by $11$. 
From $19\equiv{-3}\pmod{11}$ and $92\equiv4\pmod{11}$ we deduce easily these factors. By Fermat's little theorem, the powers modulo $11$ are periodically repeated of ten in ten. We'll  go till $P_{15}$.

The first $15$ powers modulo $11$ of $19$ are

$$-3\hspace{5mm}9\hspace{5mm}{-5}\hspace{5mm}4\hspace{5mm}\color{red}{-1}\hspace{5mm}3\hspace{5mm}2\hspace{8mm}5\hspace{5mm}{-4}\hspace{5mm}{1}\hspace{5mm}{-3}\hspace{5mm}9\hspace{5mm}{-5}\hspace{5mm}4\hspace{5mm}\color{red}{-1}$$ and the first $15$ powers modulo $11$ 0f $92$ are
$$4\hspace{6mm}5\hspace{4mm}{-2}\hspace{6mm}3\hspace{6mm}\color{red}{1}\hspace{6mm}4\hspace{6mm}5\hspace{6mm}-2\hspace{6mm}3\hspace{6mm}1\hspace{6mm}{4 }\hspace{6mm}5\hspace{6mm}{-2}\hspace{7mm}3\hspace{5mm}\color{red}{1}$$ It is clear that we should only focus on the powers whose sum is $0$ modulo $11$ which we have put in red but we do all the (unnecessary) calculations anyway for clarity for everyone

.

$$19+92\equiv -3+4\equiv1\pmod{11}\\19^2+92^2\equiv 9+5\equiv3\pmod{11}\\19^3+92^3\equiv -5-2\equiv4\pmod{11}\\19^4+92^4\equiv 4+3\equiv7\pmod{11}\\19^5+92^5\equiv -1+1\color{red}{\equiv0}\pmod{11}\\19^6+92^6\equiv 3+4\equiv7\pmod{11}\\19^7+92^7\equiv 2+5\equiv7\pmod{11}\\19^8+92^8\equiv 5-2\equiv3\pmod{11}\\19^9+92^9\equiv -4+3\equiv-1\pmod{11}\\19^{10}+92^{10}\equiv 1+1\equiv2\pmod{11}\\19^{11}+92^{11}\equiv -3+4\equiv1\pmod{11}\\19^{12}+92^{12}\equiv 9+5\equiv3\pmod{11}\\19^{13}+92^{13}\equiv -5-2\equiv4\pmod{11}\\19^{14}+92^{14}\equiv 4+3\equiv7\pmod{11}\\19^{15}+92^{15}\equiv -1+1\color{red}{\equiv0}\pmod{11}$$

Now we verify that $19^5+92^5$ is really exactly divisible by $11^2$ and so is for $19^{5n}+92^{5n}$ for $n$ odd and it is not so for $n$ even.

It follows that  $P_{30}$ is exactly divisible by $11^6$ (for exponents $5,15$ and $25$) and that $P_{150}$ is divisible by $11^{30}$. Going till $P_{155}$ it is divisible by $11^{32}$ because just the exponent $155$ is involved. However we can verified that $19^{55}+92^{55}$ is exactly divisible by $11^3$. In fact
$$19^{55}=(19^11)^5\equiv 118^5\equiv846\pmod{11^3}\\92^{55}=(92^11)^5\equiv(1291^5\equiv485\pmod{11^3}\\\text{ then }19^{55}+92^{55}\equiv846+485=11^3$$ Similarly we verified that $19^{55}+92^{55}$ is not divisible by $11^4$ and that the other involved 
exponents they are exactly divisible by $11^2$.

Thus the minimum required for $n$ is $155$.

Comment: But why would $19^{5n}+92^{5n}$ not have a factor of $11^3$ for odd $n$?

Comment: Take the quotient $\dfrac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}$ with the hypothesis of the problem.Maybe I am wrong in this?

Comment: @Mike: Maybe you can use this fact (known in the early history of FLT) $$gcd\left(a+b,\dfrac{a^n+b^n}{a+b}\right)=gcd(n,a+b)$$. The most of the cases this gcd is $1$.

Comment: Well but of course this gcd is bounded by $a+b=121$. I am asking about $a^n+b^n$ dividing higher powers of [here] 11.

Comment: And infact $11^3|(19^{55}+92^{55})$ according to someone's calculation above, and I am not sure if there isn't an even higher power of 11 hidden in there. So respectfully, what you have really is not an answer and should be editted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you dear friend. I have verified that $19^{55}+92^{55}$ is exactly divisible by $11^3$ as you say then this is so for the exponent  $165$ (and that  $19^{165}+92^{165}$ is not divisible by $11^4$!!!!). However it is not necessary  go till 165 because the end is found if  $19^{45}+92^{45}$ is exactly divisible by $11^2$.  Consequently , we stop at $n=155$. I'll corrige after. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT:

$19^n+92^n ≡ 8^n+4^n \ mod (11)$

⇒ $4^n(2^n+1)=11 k$

One solution of this equation is $n=5$, $k=3 \times 1024$, we have:

$4^5(2^5+1)=1024\times 33$

Therefor for $n=5$ and all powers such as $5(2t+1)$ , $19^n+92^n ≡ 0 \mod (33)$ due to geometric progression:

$(19^5)^{2t+1}+(92^5)^{2t+1}=(19^5+92^5)[(19^5)^{2t}-(19^5)^{2t-1}(92^5) + . . . + (92^5)^{2t}]$

We can see that $19^5+92^5$ is divisible by $11^2$ :

$19^5+92^5= 121\times 54490011 $

so we need to have $33/2=16.5$ factors of such kind; we may guess  $n=33\times 5=165$. But for this we have 165 times 3 and 17 times power of 5(from 5 to 165) so the product contains a factor like:

$P=3^{165 }\times 11^{2\times 17\times 5=170}$

So it seems $n=165$ is sufficient. The result from brute force , i.e $n=155=31\times 5$, indicates that there must be two hidden power for 33 such that  we can get equal powers for 3 and 11.That is  two of 5th powers must be divisible by $11^3$.If so power of 11 will be:

$(17-2=15)\times 2+1)\times 5=155$

Comment: it is ridiculous, I am down voted for the shortest possible correct solution. It is just discouraging.The presence of such an antique members in this site is a catastrophe.

Comment: I did not downvote. However, I do have questions about what you wrote, and I can see why others had issues with your answer. 1) You attempted to show that $n=165$ is *sufficient* but you did not prove it is *necessary*. There may be higher powers of 3 or 11 hidden in $19^n+92^n$. Also, why is it so that $33|19^5+92^5$ implies that $33|19^n+92^n$ for all odd multiples of $5$?

Comment: @Mike, thank you for your comment. This is an active response to an attempt to answer a question. This helps the improvement of solution. Down voting is a passive response which usually causes discourage. I will consider your points and try to make the  answer better.

Comment: this does clear up why is it so that $33|19^5+92^5$ implies that $33|19^n+92^n$ for all odd multiples of 5. However, I am not following why $n=155$ suffices from your reasoning. Meanwhile in general if a response is only a partial solution, then I think that should be mentioned outright e.g., "this shows $n=165$ is sufficient but $n$ may be smaller..." Otherwise it may be taken as someone trying to pose an imcomplete/incorrect answer as the correct one, and that IME gets the downvotes

Comment: To clarify, I can see that $n=155$ suffices as $11^3|19^{55}+92^{55}$, but you don't seem to be using that.... You need to have both 11 a factor at least 33 times and 3 a factor at least 33 times...